# Java Lab 9.18 Plant Information

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, split, abstract-class

I am having trouble parsing string input from a user into a string array in order to store unique responses into an ArrayList.

The user inputs data like this:

```
plant Spirea 10 
flower Hydrangea 30 false lilac 
flower Rose 6 false white
plant Mint 4
-1
```

-1 signals the end of user input.

Here is the prompt:

> Given a base Plant class and a derived Flower class, complete main() to create an ArrayList called myGarden. The ArrayList should be able to store objects that belong to the Plant class or the Flower class. Create a method called printArrayList(), that uses the printInfo() methods defined in the respective classes and prints each element in myGarden. The program should read plants or flowers from input (ending with -1), add each Plant or Flower to the myGarden ArrayList, and output each element in myGarden using the printInfo() method.

below is my current code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.lang.String;

public class PlantArrayListExample {

   // TODO: Define a printArrayList method that prints an ArrayList of plant (or flower) objects     
   public static void printArrayList(ArrayList<Plant> myGarden) {
      for (int i = 0; i < myGarden.size(); i++) {
        myGarden.get(i).printInfo();
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String input;
      // TODO: Declare an ArrayList called myGarden that can hold object of type plant
      ArrayList<Plant> myGarden = new ArrayList<Plant>();

      // TODO: Declare variables - plantName, plantCost, colorOfFlowers, isAnnual
      String plantName;
      String plantCost;
      String colorOfFLowers;
      boolean isAnnual;
      
      input = scnr.next();

      while(!input.equals("-1")){
         
          String[] info = input.split(" ");
          
         // TODO: Check if input is a plant or flower 
          //       Store as a plant object or flower object
        if (info[0].toLowerCase().equals("plant")) {
            Plant p1 = new Plant();
               p1.setPlantName(info[1]);
               p1.setPlantCost(info[2]);
               myGarden.add(p1);
         }
        else if (info[0].toLowerCase().equals("flower")) {
           Flower f1 = new Flower();
            f1.setPlantName(info[1]);
            f1.setPlantCost(info[2]);
            f1.setPlantType(Boolean.parseBoolean(info[3]));
            f1.setColorOfFlowers(info[4]);
            myGarden.add(f1);
         }
         else {
            continue;
         }
         input = scnr.next();
      }
      
      // TODO: Call the method printArrayList to print myGarden
      printArrayList(myGarden);
      
   }
}
```

Tried to parse string input into an array using .split() method. I am able to successfully parse a single string of user input outside of the while loop without issues. There are two java files not posted as these are already done for you. If you believe it will help resolve my issue, please let me know and I will post that information as well.

Comment: Replace `next()` with `nextLine()`

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe it was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing these:

```
 myGarden.add(new Flower());
 myGarden.add(new Plant());
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).